# How to describe an explanation that merely justifies the current proposition by reference to another unproven proposition?

Tags: rhetoric

I'm proposing an explanation for phenomenon "A". Other folks say "No need! We already have an explanation for phenomenon A, it's a natural consequence of phenomenon B". Problem is, phenomenon B is also unexplained. I want to call this out in a polite but firm way.

I've thought of:

> This pushes the question off onto unexplained "B"

> This is merely shifting the burden of explanation.

This is probably a logical fallacy with a Name and Employment History, but I can't think what it is. Any thoughts?

Thanks! =)

Comment: Under your proposition, is phenomenon A still a natural consequence of phenomenon B?

Comment: I think this is a hasty generalization. You are supporting a conclusion based on inadequate evidence.  I'm afraid my logic class is many years out of date, though https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/academic_writing/logic_in_argumentative_writing/fallacies.html  It is also an example of insufficient Evidence https://app.shoreline.edu/doldham/SRR.html It isn't a whole answer, though.

Comment: It may also qualify as a loaded (complex) question. Not sure. http://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/fallacies_list.html It is certainly an assumption https://app.shoreline.edu/doldham/101/HTML/Assumptions.htm

Comment: Phenomenon B and my explanation are both sufficient (but not necessary) causes.

Comment: So your explanation is an alternative explanation of phenomenon A? I see several different causations here: [smth] => B (unproven), B => A (tell us!), [smth] => A (your proposition). Do you need to disprove B => A to substantiate your proposition?